# ipad application or web?

Tags: ipad, web-applications

I have a question regarding development for Ipad.

Is there an advantage to develop an application with iOS over using a regular development for web application that can be opened in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adobe just released a study here

http://www.fiercemobilecontent.com/press-releases/adobe-mobile-study-reveals-consumer-preferences-accessing-consumer-products-shopping-

it details which apps users expect to be apps and which they expect to be web based

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you want to do in the application. iOS has numerous features that are not available in a web browser including using integrated hardware (accelerometer, mic,camera) and a lot of built in forms and widgets in the sdk that just don't really exist for web dev.

That said there a lot of features that you could easily provide via a webpage. Really use case and feature set will help determine what is best for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are many advantages, but that doesn't mean you should always develop an iOS native application. Examples where you will take advantage of a full iOS native application:

1. A game using OpenGL ES (can't do it on the WEB)
2. UI taking advantage of Multitouch input
3. Application that you can use offline
4. Specialized hardware (GPS, accelerometer, camera {in the future?})

As most of the things in computer science, the best choice will depend on what you are trying to build/accomplish.